# On the euler characteristic and gluing polyhedra

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have to polyhedra, say $A$ a,d $B$ with euler characteristic $\chi(A)$ and $\chi(B)$. If we glue the two polyhedra along a face (assuming they have two faces that coincide), can we argue that $\chi(A+B) = \chi(A) + \chi(B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the glued face is an $n$-gon. If the numbers of faces, edges and vertices of a polyhedron $C$ are denoted by $f(C),e(C)$ and $v(C)$ respectively, then the glueing process means that

- $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)-2$ (the two faces glued together disappear)
- $e(A+B)=e(A)+e(B)-n$ ($n$ pairs of edges are glued together, so $2n$ becomes $n$)
- $v(A+B)=v(A)+v(B)-n$ (same here).

So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\chi(A+B)&=f(A+B)-e(A+B)+v(A+B)\\
&=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-2+n-n\\
&=\chi(A)+\chi(B)-2.
\end{aligned}
$$